# Mostrar informacion de una lista C#

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Requiero de su valiosa ayuda con este inconveniente. Necesito hacer un ejercicio sobre entrada y salida de vehículos de un parqueadero en C#. No soy estudiante de nivel básico.

He utilizado constructor, encapsulamiento mediante SET/GET, metodos, también he creado listas para guardar la información que el usuario agregara. Pero no he logrado que en consola se muestre la información que el usuario registra. Siempre muestra información vacía. Nota, aclaro que utilizo el método ToString, para que me pueda mostrar información pero no ha servido. Quedo atento a sus valiosas recomendaciones. Aclaro, cree 6 clases para este proyecto de parqueadero.

Les dejo el código de la clase persona, que es la clase padre, de las clases clientes y empleados.

```
namespace Parqueadero
{
    internal class Persona
    {
        //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES
        private string nombre = "";
        private string apellido = "";
        private double identificacion;
        private double telefono;
        private List<Persona> personas;

        //METODO CONSTRUCTOR
        public Persona(string nombres, string apellidos, double identificacion, double telefono)
        {
            this.nombre = nombres;
            this.apellido = apellidos;
            this.identificacion = identificacion;
            this.telefono = telefono;

            personas = new List<Persona>();
            
        }

        
        //ENCAPSULAMIENTO MEDIANTE LOS METODOS SET / GET
        public string getNombre()
        {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(string nombre)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public string getApellido()
        {
            return apellido;
        }
        public void setApellido(string apellido)
        {
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }

        public double getIdentificacion()
        {
            return identificacion;
        }

        public void setIdentificacion(int identificacion)
        {
            this.identificacion = identificacion;
        }

        public double getTelefono()
        {
            return telefono;
        }

        public void setTelefono(double telefono)
        {
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }
        //METODO PARA BUSCAR UNA PERSONA EN LA LISTA
        public Persona Buscar(double identificacion)
        {
            Persona buscada = null;
            bool encontrado = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < personas.Count && encontrado == false; i++)
            {
                if (personas[i].getIdentificacion() == identificacion)
                {
                    buscada = personas[i];
                    encontrado = true;
                }
            }

            return buscada;
        }
      
        public override String ToString()
        {
            return " Nombre: " + nombre + "\n " + " apellido: " + apellido + "\n " + "identificacion: " + identificacion + "\n " + "telefono: " + telefono ;
        }

        //METODO PARA REGISTRA A UNA PERSONA EN LA LISTA
        public void Registro(string nombres, string apellidos, double identificacion, double telefono)
        {
            Persona buscada = Buscar(identificacion);
            if (buscada == null)
            {
                Persona nueva = new Persona(nombre, apellido, identificacion, telefono);
                personas.Add(nueva);
                Console.WriteLine("La persona ha sido registrada");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n La persona ya se encuentra registrada en la lista ");
            }

        }

        //Metodo para la eliminacion de una persona
        public void Eliminar(double identificacion)
        {
            Persona buscada = Buscar(identificacion);
            if(buscada != null)
            {
                personas.Remove(buscada);
                Console.WriteLine("La persona {0}, ha sido eliminada", buscada);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n La persona no puede ser eliminada debido a que no se encuentra en la lista");
            }

        }
        public void Mostrar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n DATOS CLIENTE");
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre cliente: {0}", getNombre());
            Console.WriteLine("Apellido: {0}", getApellido());
            Console.WriteLine("Identificación {0}", getIdentificacion());
            Console.WriteLine("Telefono {0}", getTelefono());
        }

    }//FIN CLASE PERSONA
}//FIN NAMESPACE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado tu código y funciona, a mi me muestra la información.

Creo que tu error puede estar en la implementación de la clase, porque tienes un  "error" de modelado. Tienes una lista de personas en la clase persona, es decir cada persona crea su propia lista, lo cual no tiene mucho sentido. Deberías crear la lista como static o crear una clase extra.

También tienes un error en el registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El argumento de entrada es nombres con S final, y tu creas la persona con nombre sin S final.

Por otro lado, creas muchas funciones para setear tus variables (esto lo veo mucho en desarrolladores que vienen de JAVA), en C# no es necesario hacerlo de esta manera, en c# se ocupan propiedades

Dejo un ejemplo

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();

        agenda.Registro("nombre1", "apellido1", 1, 1);
        agenda.Registro("nombre2", "apellido2", 2, 2);
        agenda.Registro("nombre3", "apellido2", 3, 3);
        agenda.Mostrar();
           
    }

    public class Agenda
    {
        private List<Persona> personas=new List<Persona>();

        //METODO PARA BUSCAR UNA PERSONA EN LA LISTA
        public Persona? Buscar(double identificacion)
        {
            return personas.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.identificacion==identificacion);
        }

        //METODO PARA REGISTRA A UNA PERSONA EN LA LISTA
        public void Registro(string nombres, string apellidos, double identificacion, double telefono)
        {
            Persona? buscada = Buscar(identificacion);
            if (buscada == null)
            {
                Persona nueva = new Persona(nombres, apellidos, identificacion, telefono);
                personas.Add(nueva);
                Console.WriteLine("La persona ha sido registrada");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n La persona ya se encuentra registrada en la lista ");
            }

        }

        //Metodo para la eliminacion de una persona
        public void Eliminar(double identificacion)
        {
            Persona buscada = Buscar(identificacion);
            if (buscada != null)
            {
                personas.Remove(buscada);
                Console.WriteLine("La persona {0}, ha sido eliminada", buscada);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n La persona no puede ser eliminada debido a que no se encuentra en la lista");
            }

        }

        public void Mostrar()
        {
            foreach(var p in personas)
            {
                p.Mostrar();
            }
        }

    }
    internal class Persona
    {
        //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public double identificacion { get; set; }
        public double telefono { get; set; }
   

        //METODO CONSTRUCTOR
        public Persona(string nombres, string apellidos, double identificacion, double telefono)
        {
            this.nombre = nombres;
            this.apellido = apellidos;
            this.identificacion = identificacion;
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return @$"Nombre: {nombre}
apellido: {apellido}
identificacion: {identificacion}
telefono: {telefono}";
        }

           
        public void Mostrar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n DATOS CLIENTE");
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre cliente: {0}", nombre);
            Console.WriteLine("Apellido: {0}",apellido);
            Console.WriteLine("Identificación {0}", identificacion);
            Console.WriteLine("Telefono {0}", telefono);
        }

    }//FIN CLASE PERSONA
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]